# Django Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'mydomain'. You may need to add u'mydomain' to ALLOWED_HOSTS

Tags: django, digital-ocean

This comes up when I try to access my site with the domain name, but it works fine when I use the IP address. I've tried adding 'mydomain', u'mydomain', and my IP address to ALLOWED_HOSTS in settings.py, but always get this error

Comment: please post your settings.py

Comment: (Or at least just the bit around `ALLOWED_HOSTS`.)

Comment: ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['wordpiles.com', '159.89.95.78']

Answer (score 7):

if you want to access your website on IP and using domain, use below code in settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['<domain name>', '<Ip address>']
```

Comment: I currently have ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['wordpiles.com', '159.89.95.78'] and it still isn't working. Is there anything else that would cause this?

Comment: Don't forget to restart your server after you made the change. The DEBUG output error page still shows the old, outdated settings.

Comment: I run service gunicorn restart then refresh after making changes. Still seeing the same error.

Comment: I checked your allowed host, firstly debug false your project and add website name in allowed host ['127.0.0.1', '::1', '159.89.95.78', 'fe80::bc96:d5ff:fe9c:b11%eth0']

Comment: My allowed hosts is currently ['127.0.0.1', '::1', '159.89.95.78', 'fe80::bc96:d5ff:fe9c:b11%eth0', 'wordpiles.com'] and still doesn't work. Is it possible the problem is elsewhere?

Comment: I think problem is somewhere. because i checked your website there not showing your domain name into allowhost. when you got that yellow error page, search allowhost. there you will see ypur domain is not in allowhost

Comment: I see. It isn't showing the domain in the allowed hosts on the debug page even though it is in settings.py. I've resaved, and restarted and it still isn't coming through.

Comment: I changed it to str(wordpiles.com). now I'm getting 502 bad gateway, but I think that's separate issue. Thanks for the help.